# How to access a website's robots.txt

Tags: java, url, robots.txt

I have a Java program and I am writing a method that accepts an URL as an argument. Is there a way to have the method return a copy of the 'robots.txt' (e.g. https://www.google.com/robots.txt) file associated with the URL I am passing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show what you have / check the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now next to nothing about robot.txt, but I seem to remember, you store it in root-path always. So I believe a method like `getRobot()` in example below should work fine for you:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class Robots {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Robots().getRobot("http://www.google.de/q?Stack Overflow"));
    }

    public String getRobot(String url) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http(s?)://([^/]+))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            try (InputStream in = new URL(m.group(1) + "/robots.txt").openStream()) {
                return IOUtils.toString(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "no robots allowed";
    }
}
```

Check out `main()` for working example

Comment: And you could add some simple URL parsing to ensure the URL us always server URL only. I think even simple regex could do it.

Comment: So it's about passing just *any* URL in? Yeah, that's simple regex.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!